# doubts about power supply wattage on my future build

Tags: power-supply, ventilation

I'm building a new pc for a personal cloud server and I was thinking about buying the following:

- Motherboard: MSI AM1I
- CPU: AMD Athlon 5350
- Ram: HyperX Fury Blue DDR3 1600MHz PC3-12800 4GB
- One sata HDD (I will be reusing it and don't remember its specs)

I had read that the power supply wattage should be in a certain range and almost all the PSU I have found didn't meet this criteria. i.e. My build has a power usage of 72-94w so a 150w PSU will be optimal but I only found  500w PSUs because of my reduced budget (50€ for the case and PSU)
However, I had found two cases with a PSU that seems good. The first one is a Nox Vexa with a 150w PSU and the other is a Tacens Ixion with a 300w PSU.

I would like to buy the first, but I'm worried if I could get to fit the CPU fan in it and also if the CPU would have enough ventilation. Also, I'm a bit worried about the noise they can make because I have seen some comments saying that they do pretty noise but, also, some saying that they are very silent.
Should I buy the first, the second or try with a 500w ATX PSU and a case that allow me to use it?

Comment: Look into pico-psu combined with external 12V power brick. It wont be as cheap as 50€ if bought new, but you can source the pico from Aliexpress, used brick (from old Dell USFF) from ebay and solder them together.

Answer (score 0):

As khmer11 said, the PSUs in cases are terrible. A 150w - 300w PSU will be optimal and be at peak efficiency, but a 400-500w PSU will still work well. If you choose the 150w - 300w PSU then you will be limited if you do any upgrades (e.g. change to a more powerful CPU or add a GPU) but it you will be fine if you choose the 400 - 500w PSU. Another thing you should look for when choosing PSU is the efficiency rating. I recommend at least 80 Plus Bronze rating since it is a good combination of good efficiency, value and durability.

Comment: Efficiency goes down the drain if PSU is loaded below 50%. OP is right, shitty PSU at right load is better than good PSU at wrong one.

Comment: @Agent_L Not really, if you had a Gold rated 500w PSU it will be more efficient than a generic 300w PSU at peak efficiency. It will also be more reliable.

Comment: 80Plus certify at 20%, 50% and 80% load. Loadings as low as OP's (72W off 500W PSU ia about 14%) are beyond scope of 80Plus ratings.

Answer (score -2):

Personally speaking, the power supplies that come with cases are normally not very good. I tend to buy just standard ATX PSU's for my builds. They are very quiet. I don't think you will be drawing enough power to make it kick in the fans on full mode but you should be fine with either option.

In my freeNAS server, I have a Corsair 500w power supply. Whisper quiet. The only noise that comes from the tower is the CPU fan.